# Best way to summarize many consecutive if(x typeof !=='unedfined') queries?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I writing testscripts with JavaScript and Selenium and I want to query, if the optional parameter are given, if so, then use them, if not, skip them.

```
/*optional parameter are: day, month, year, comment*/

if( typeof day !== 'undefined') {
entryField.sendKeys(day);
}

if( typeof year!== 'undefined') {
entryField.sendKeys(year);
}

if( typeof month!== 'undefined') {
entryField.sendKeys(month);
}

if( typeof comment !== 'undefined') {
entryField.sendKeys(comment);
}
```

That looks very ugly. Is there a better way to do it?
The parameter are given from outside, so if I do not do this typeof-Query, an reference error occurs, because they are not defined.

Comment: If they're actually parameters, as you say, then there shouldn't be any ReferenceError problem, their values will just be `undefined`. If there are ReferenceErrors, then those are not parameters. I suppose you could `eval` to be more DRY, but dynamic variable names are *very* strange, sounds X/Y-ish

Comment: Can you add the code where you specify these parameters?

Comment: We have an own coded testrunner with an webInterface - The written testscripts are uploaded,and the used parameters can be given through the webinterface, so if I do not give these parameters, but use them in the testscript without the query above, the error occurs, because it is like using a variable that is not even declared.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part, I assume, is that the variable `day` etc. might not even exist before this part of the code. So to avoid getting errors, one possible way is to use `eval`, like this:

```
var para = ["day", "year", "month", "comment"];
for(let p of para) {
    if(eval("typeof "+p) !== 'undefined') {
        entryField.sendKeys(eval(p));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ironically, this appears to be the only correct answer so far. Whether this is better than the OP's code though is debatable.\

Comment: Well, if he has like a lot and a lot of parameters to check, then the answer is probably yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a forEach, with an array of actions, for a more readable approach:

```
var actions = [day, year, month, comment]

actions.forEach(action => {
  if (typeof action !== 'undefined') {
    entryField.sendKeys(action);
  }
})
```

Comment: The problem is, these vars might not be defined at all (see the OP's comments).

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a rest parameter, so instead of `fn(day, year, month, comment)` I'd do:

```
   function fn(...keys) {
     keys.filter(it => it !== undefined)
       .forEach(it => entryField.sendKeys(it));
   }
```